# Issue with running script using Locklift - Cannot find module '01-deploy-token.ts

Tags: venom

I am encountering an issue while trying to run a script using Locklift. Specifically, I am unable to find the module '01-deploy-token.ts' when attempting to execute the command. I have followed the recommended steps and suggestions, but the problem persists.

Here are the details of the situation:

Command used:

```
npx locklift run -n local -s scripts/01-deploy-token.ts
```

Error message:

> Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\my-first-token\scripts\01-deploy-token.ts'

I have already taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

- Verified the existence of the '01-deploy-token.ts' file in the 'scripts' directory at the correct location: C:\Users\DELL\my-first-token\scripts.
- Checked the accuracy of the file name and path, ensuring they are correctly entered in the command.
- Confirmed that the command is being executed from the correct directory by using the cd command to navigate to C:\Users\DELL\my-first-token.
- Attempted to run the script using a relative path: npx locklift run -n local -s ./scripts/01-deploy-token.ts.

Despite these efforts, I have not been able to resolve the issue. The error messages received include phrases such as "'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command" and "'generated' is not recognized as an internal or external command."